# setStatusBarOrientation causing problems in iOS8

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, interface, orientation, ios8

I'm having real problems with my apps under iOS8. I've made a bunch of OpenGL based apps, which don't need the iOS to handle the orientation. It's all handled within the OpenGL section. But I do use setStatusBarOrientation to make sure any dialogs/keyboards etc that pop up line up with everything else. I'm creating my window and view programatically or in a xib, I've never needed to use a storyboard (in case thats relevant?)

It's all been perfect, til iOS 8 came along.

Now it seems that setStatusBarOrientation isn't behaving properly at all. It's either not changing anything, or it's rotating "something" that stops touches being recorded on half the screen. It's as if the window is being rotated within itself, but visually nothing changes, just the touches are effected.

It's hard to explain, and makes no sense.

But my question is: How do you set the status bar orientation in iOS8? And how do you do it without destroying everything else that works in previous iOS versions?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. I'm manually rotating the view using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation.

Comment: Also having the same issue as @jarrold. Were you able to find a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Set iOS7.1 as your Base SDK, and it'll work fine on iOS8, without all these strange bugs.

http://objcsharp.wordpress.com/2014/09/21/how-to-get-back-the-ios-7-sdk-after-upgrading-to-xcode-6/

Answer (score -2):

found this

```
if ([UIViewController class]) // iOS8 has this class only
{
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait] forKey:@"orientation"];
}
```

found here: 
http://blog.lessfun.com/blog/2014/09/24/ios8-issue-keyboard-orientation-and-idletimerdisabled-not-working/

seems to work

Comment: But would this be kosher with an app in the app store?